# Shortcut key for multiplication sign

Tags: mathematica

What is the shortcut key for making the "`×`" multiplication sign in Mathematica (n.b. `× != x`)?

You can enter all the other three basic arithmetic operators by simply typing "`+`", "`-`" and "`/`" (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>).

Comment: Why `x`?  The asterisk `*` is the *widely used* and **standardized** multiplication symbol.  Also, Ctrl+X is cut in all operating systems, so you won't be able to do this anyways... Plus, what about variable names?  How would you reference (or even define) them if you did this?  Just use `*` and be done with it.

Comment: Okay i'll just use `·` then, as it's standard in my country.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Asterisk as multiplication is only standard in programming/computing. "·" and "×" are by far the [more standard symbols for multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign) in typesetting and writing. This was [discussed](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/4zYQJxo8fYw) on [mathgroup](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/GtQuiKYvgjo) a [couple](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/QKu6HA9qWG0) of times recently.

Comment: Aside: the common division symbol "`÷`" (called the obelus) is entered into Mma using `Esc div Esc`. All of the input aliases and more can be found at [tutorial/Operators](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Operators.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the Mathematica documentation for "times" (which is the first place you should always check for questions like this) it gives you the key sequence `Esc * Esc` (escape-asterisk-escape). It has exactly the same meaning as a plain asterisk so pretty much nobody actually uses this symbol.